# UDP tracker scrape in node.js returning zero unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp, bittorrent

I'm trying to perform a UDP scrape from public UDP trackers such as tracker.publicbt.com or tracker.openbittorrent.com using the [BitTorrent UDP Tracker Protocol](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html). My app sends a request to the tracker for a connection_id and uses that id to perform a scrape. The scrape response is returned from the tracker, with no errors to indicate a badly formed packet, but no matter what info_hash I use, I get "0" returned for the numbers of seeders, leechers and completed.

I've thoroughly checked that the packet is the right size, that the info_hash starts at the correct offset, and that the data are all correct. As far as I can see, there are no problems creating and sending the packet. This question's been open and unanswered for a few days, so I've updated and edited the code example below in the hope someone can help.

I've hardcoded an info_hash into the following example. When run on the command line this code should connect to the tracker, get a connection_id and then perform a scrape on an Ubuntu torrent info_hash, outputting various bits of info to the console.

The connection_id is split into 2 parts because it is a 64 bit integer.

```
var dgram = require('dgram'),
    server = dgram.createSocket("udp4"),
    connectionIdHigh = 0x417,
    connectionIdLow = 0x27101980,
    transactionId,
    action,
    trackerHost = "tracker.publicbt.com",
    trackerPort = 80,
    infoHash = "",
    ACTION_CONNECT = 0,
    ACTION_ANNOUNCE = 1,
    ACTION_SCRAPE = 2,
    ACTION_ERROR = 3,
    sendPacket = function (buf, host, port) {
        "use strict";
        server.send(buf, 0, buf.length, port, host, function(err, bytes) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        });
    },
    startConnection = function (host, port) {
        "use strict";
        var buf = new Buffer(16);

        transactionId = Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+1);

        buf.fill(0);

        buf.writeUInt32BE(connectionIdHigh, 0);
        buf.writeUInt32BE(connectionIdLow, 4);
        buf.writeUInt32BE(ACTION_CONNECT, 8);
        buf.writeUInt32BE(transactionId, 12);

        sendPacket(buf, host, port);
    },
    scrapeTorrent = function (host, port, hash) {
        "use strict";
        var buf = new Buffer(56),
            tmp = '';

        infoHash = hash;

        if (!transactionId) {
            startConnection(host, port);
        } else {

            buf.fill(0);

            buf.writeUInt32BE(connectionIdHigh, 0);
            buf.writeUInt32BE(connectionIdLow, 4);
            buf.writeUInt32BE(ACTION_SCRAPE, 8);
            buf.writeUInt32BE(transactionId, 12);
            buf.write(infoHash, 16, buf.length);

            console.log(infoHash);
            console.log(buf.toString('utf8', 16, buf.length));

            // do scrape
            sendPacket(buf, host, port);

            transactionId = null;
            infoHash = null;
        }

    };

server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
    "use strict";
    var buf = new Buffer(msg),
        seeders,
        completed,
        leechers;

    console.log(rinfo);

    action = buf.readUInt32BE(0, 4);
    transactionId = buf.readUInt32BE(4, 4);

    console.log("returned action: " + action);
    console.log("returned transactionId: " + transactionId);

    if (action === ACTION_CONNECT) {
        console.log("connect response");

        connectionIdHigh = buf.readUInt32BE(8, 4);
        connectionIdLow = buf.readUInt32BE(12, 4);

        scrapeTorrent(trackerHost, trackerPort, infoHash);

    } else if (action === ACTION_SCRAPE) {
        console.log("scrape response");

        seeders = buf.readUInt32BE(8, 4);
        completed = buf.readUInt32BE(12, 4);
        leechers = buf.readUInt32BE(16, 4);

        console.log(seeders);
        console.log(completed);
        console.log(leechers);

    } else if (action === ACTION_ERROR) {
        console.log("error response");
    }
});

server.on("listening", function () {
    "use strict";
    var address = server.address();
    console.log("server listening " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.bind();

scrapeTorrent(trackerHost, trackerPort, "335990D615594B9BE409CCFEB95864E24EC702C7");
```

Comment: I've added a slightly improved code example above. Over the past few days I've been trying to identify if there is something wrong with the way I've created the buffer, but as far as I can tell the fields are all correct, including the info_hash section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally worked this out, and kicked myself for not realising sooner.

An info_hash is a hex encoded string, so when it's written to the buffer needs to have it's encoding set. For example:

```
buf.write(infoHash, 16, buf.length, 'hex');
```

The UDP tracker protocol doesn't mention the encoding required, it just describes it as a 20 byte string. Hopefully this Q&A might help someone else who encounters the same problem.